# About Shemot 38:8

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, vayakhel

Can someone explain this passage? I absolutely do not understand where does it say anything about mirrors or women? bemarot means "in a vision" as in Bereshit 46:2 and hatsoveot means probably "enlisted ones" as in Bemidbar 4:23. So proper translation should be something along the lines of "*and he made the laver of copper and post of it copper, in a vision of the enlisted who enlisted at the portal of the tent of appointment.*" Can someone clarify these two words at least? Is it talking about some vision of the sons of Kohath, who carried the Laver? (Bemidbar 4:15)

Answer (score 6):

במראות (*bemar'ot*), while it can refer to a vision, also means mirrors -- it is the plural form of the word מראה (*mar'ah*) -- [See Wiktionary's definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%94#Noun_2).

The word הצבאות (*hatzov'ot*) is a bit ambiguous. Note that not everyone translates it as "enlisted ones" in Bamidbar -- for example, here's [Mechon Mamre's translation](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0404.htm#23) there:

> from thirty years old and upward until fifty years old shalt thou number them: all that enter in to wait upon **the service**, to **do service** in the tent of meeting.

Here too, we can translate as doing service (from [Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.38.8?lang=he-en&sidebarLang=all&layout=heLeft) this time):

> And he made the laver of brass, and the base thereof of brass, of the mirrors of the **serving women** that did **service** at the door of the tent of meeting.

We know it refers to women because the word is in feminine form.

I should point out that many commentators follow [Rashi here](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9899#showrashi=true&v=8) with an aggadic explanation. The women in Egypt would use their mirrors to beautify themselves and convince their husbands to be with them, and they gave birth to many legions (צבא).

---

It has nothing to do with Kehat or visions.

Comment: So, you mean like in 1 Shmuel 2:22? But who were these women?

Comment: They were the women of B'nei Yisrael who donated their mirrors.

Comment: No, who are they? Why they serve in the sanctuary? Are they kohanim wifes/daughters?

Comment: 1) see my previous comment 2) i wouldn't say that they serve *in* the sanctuary -- more that they serve the sanctuary itself by donating their mirrors. 3) no, see my previous comment again.

Comment: Thanks but this does not really answer my question

Comment: If it doesn't answer your question, perhaps you should clarify your question.

Comment: @Scimonster [Alternatively](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9899 jewish/Chapter-38.htm#v=8&showrashi=true) *And he made the  washstand of copper and its base of copper from the mirrors of the women who had set up the legions, who congregated at the entrance of the tent of meeting.* This explains how Rashi uses the explanation. The term is related to *army* or *gathered*